# pointer arithmetic: address with no assignment holds value of another address

Tags: c, pointers

why is the address `px+1` holding the value 0.3? (on every execution) the variable `f` has also the value 0.3, but it has an other address(px-1)!? (even the values on `px+2`, `px+3` and `px-2` hold the value 0.3..., when I print it out)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  int* px;
  int i = 1;
  float f= 0.3;
  double d=0.005;
  char c = '*';

  px=&i;
  printf("Values: i=%i f=%f d=%f c=%c\n",i,f,d,c);

  printf("Addresses: i=%lX f=%lX d=%lX c=%lX\n",&i,&f,&d,&c);

  printf("Pointer Values (size of int = %d):\n px=%lX; px+1=%lX;  px+2=%lX;  px+3=%lX\n",sizeof(int),px,px+1,px+2,px+3);

  printf("Dereference: at px+1=%lX, value is:%f \n",px+1,*(px+1));

  /* Output :
Values: i=1 f=0.300000 d=0.005000 c=*
Addresses: i=7FFF5C546BB4 f=7FFF5C546BB0 d=7FFF5C546BA8 c=7FFF5C546BA7
Pointer Values (size of int = 4):
 px=7FFF5C546BB4; px+1=7FFF5C546BB8;  px+2=7FFF5C546BBC;  px+3=7FFF5C546BC0
Dereference: at px+1=7FFF5C546BB8, value is:0.300000 
   */

}
```

Comment: accessing out of bound memory is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several problems, all leading to *undefined behavior*. First of all, you should use `"%p"` to print pointers, and the pointers should be casted to `void *` for maximum compatibility. Secondly, dereferencing a pointer out of bounds, like when you do `*(px + 1)` leads to undefined behavior. Thirdly, the pointer `px` points to an *integer*, but you try to print it using `float` conversion which also leads to undefined behavior.

Comment: What means casting a pointer to void *? Is it madatory to use %p to print pointers?

Comment: @AkaiShuichi Try using "`%x"` to print a pointer on a 64-bit system and you will notice that the output will be missing quite a few bits. It's because `"%x"` is for outputting an `int` which is usually 32 bits on 64 bit systems.The `"%p"` format will expect a `void *`, and it doesn't really matter what it points to, and the output will be correct no matter platform or system.

Answer (score 0):

By writing `*(px+1)`, you're trying to access out of bound memory. It invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Also,

- to print an address, you should be using the `%p` format specifier.
- to print an `int` you should use `%d` or `%i`